# Need to combine two lambda expressions in one to execute two separate conditions of one parameter

Tags: c#, linq

`tempChoiceConfigItems` is a list and has two properties, `IsIncluded` and `IsSelected`.

In the case when both of them are true then `IsIncluded` will take preference and for that item `IsSelected` will be true and all other `IsSelected` will be false.

Can I write that in one singe lambda expression?

```cs
if (tempChoiceConfigItems.Any(cg => cg.IsIncluded == true)) {
    tempChoiceConfigItems.Where(wtci => wtci.IsIncluded == true)
    .Select(stc => {
        stc.IsSelected = true;
        return stc;
    })
    .ToList();

    tempChoiceConfigItems.Where(wtci => wtci.IsIncluded == false)
    .Select(stc => {
        stc.IsSelected = false;
        return stc;
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Remove the if clause. Try `tempChoiceConfigItems.ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = item.IsIncluded)` with an extension method like `public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action) { foreach (var item in items) action(item); }` Having this you can put the whole code into one line.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to clearly reflect what you mean. You said the list has two properties, but afterwards in your code you have accessed those two properties on list items!

Comment: @SebastianSchumann - I though of foreach but then thought can't we go without foreach?

Comment: @Som `foreach` is exactly what you need to iterate the values and update them.  Linq is for filtering and projecting one collection to another and shouldn't have side effects.  You're basically creating throw away lists just to iterate a list.

Comment: @Som why did you remove the accepted answer state from mine?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I did not removed, I thought you replaced it. That's the reason I added the refined ans.

Comment: I edited it, cause the first part wasn't correct, try the code i left there, it will produce the same result, but with less costs

Comment: @MarcoSalerno - Your foreach solution will make IsSelected to IsIncluded status. But the requirement is - if there is IsIncluded true then IsSeleted is true else not. I have added the final solution from your previous response. So thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this

```
            if (tempChoiceConfigItems.Any(cg => cg.IsIncluded == true))
            {
                tempChoiceConfigItems
                .Select(stc =>
                {
                    stc.IsSelected = stc.IsIncluded;
                    return stc;
                })
                .ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Used this instead of foreach

Answer (score 1):

Substitute all that piece of code with:

```
tempChoiceConfigItems.ForEach(x => { x.IsSelected = x.IsIncluded; });
```

Comment: But this won't change IsSelected to false for which has IsIncluded false because of where clause.

Comment: @Som I said substitute the entire code, you don't need the checks you did

Comment: this make sense.

Comment: Happy I helped you!

Comment: Ugh, side effects in LInq.  Why not just use a `forach` to modify the items in the collection?  This creates a throw away list just to iterate the items.

Comment: @juharr this is what i wrote in the 2nd part

Comment: Fair enough, though I wouldn't even bother showing the bad example as it promotes a bad coding practice.

Comment: You are right, I edited to avoid finding it in production someday ahah

Answer (score 0):

```
tempChoiceConfigItems.ForEach(x=> {if(x.IsIncluded == true && x.IsSelected==true) x.IsSelected=true; else x.IsSelected=false;});
```